# Postgres plpythonu extension doesn't exist in /usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension

Tags: postgresql

When I try to enable `plythonu` by using

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu
```

I get error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.3/share/extension/plpythonu.control": No such file or directory
```

The extension folder has no file with that name.

Is there a download link? How can I add plpythonu?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

PL/Python isn't installed. In most Linux packages of PostgreSQL it's a separate package.

If you're using apt.postgresql.org (PGDG) packages on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-plpython-9.3
```

If you're on Ubuntu or Debian with their stock PostgreSQL packages:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython
```

If you're on Fedora/CentOS/RhEL with PGDG packages from yum.postgresql.org:

```
yum install postgresql93-contrib postgresql93-plpython
```

If you're on Fedora/CentOS/RHEL with stock packages:

```
yum install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython
```

The contrib packages aren't strictly required, but you're likely to want them too.

Comment: Thank you. just figured that out and its working now. I will still select your answer as correct answer..